# How do I add something to be executed after ALL currently running animations are complete in JavaFX?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I subclassed GridPane to display tiles on my game (2048), and since animations don't work well on a GridPane, whenever the player shifts the tiles, I have a transparent Pane overlay that sits on top of the Gridpane that I shift a tile to and is the surface that my animations are run on.  My view is very "dumb" and knows nothing about the game state and simply runs animations whenever told.

I want to be able to update a few things on the Pane and the GridPane after all of the animations are complete (which it currently isn't able to do since when the animation is run it doesn't know if it's a first, intermediate, or last animation for the current game move).  This is what I use for updates after a single animation is done:

```
transition.setOnFinished(event -> {
   // executed after a single animation
}
```

However, I want to be able to do something after all active animations are complete.  Is this possible? If not what would be the best way around this?

Comment: Do you know how many animations are scheduled to run?

Comment: @James_D no, the amount depends on how many tiles are moved and how many will be combined (if they have the same value) if you know the game 2048 you'll know what I'm talking about

Comment: But then surely you know that (or can figure it out) when you start the animations? But if not, are you running them all at the same time? If so, you could put them all in a `ParallelTransition` and set an `onFinished` handler with the parallel transition.

Comment: @James_D I just get notified from my model when a cell moves or merges.  But I'm going to try that, set a parallel transition up and add an interface method to notify my view when to start it